# Excel VBA- Delete Rows where column data is ZERO

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clean up some spreadsheet data, as such I  had the below code to delete all rows for which column 10 has the number 0. The problem is when I run the code it deletes all the rows.

Would anyone be able to highlight what exactly is wrong with my code?

```
Sub Format()

Dim Fund As Long 
Dim TotalLoop As Long

RowCount = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For TotalLoop = RowCount To 2 Step -1
Fund = Cells(TotalLoop, 10)
If Fund = 0 Then
Rows(TotalLoop).Delete
Cells(TotalLoop - 1, 10) = Fund
End If
Next TotalLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the check `Cells(TotalLoop, 10) = 0` will also return true if the cell is empty. If you don't want that, use `Cells(TotalLoop, 10) = 0 And Cells(TotalLoop, 10) <> ""` or `Cells(TotalLoop, 10) = "0"` (I would use the first).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the below line and execute your code. It will work

```
Cells(TotalLoop - 1, 10) = Fund
```

Comment: kindly mark it as answer if it works by pressing tick symbol

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are changing the value of the next undeleted row to the value of fund, which is zero in order for the code to execute.  Remove the line `Cells(TotalLoop - 1, 10) = Fund` and your loop will function as desired

Answer (score 0):

Sub Format()

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Fund As Long
Dim TotalLoop As Long
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
RowCount = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


For TotalLoop = RowCount To 2 Step -1
Fund = Cells(TotalLoop, 10)
If Fund = 0 Then
Rows(TotalLoop).Delete
End If
Next TotalLoop
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks Guys. Deletion of that line helped